# boolean comparision in jquery not working?

Tags: jquery, slider, boolean

I am coding an image slider with a play/pause button, the slider wont work unless the play button is clicked, to do this I am using a boolean variable called stop, stop is false by default.

for some reason once I click the play button the boolean changes to true (I see this with an alert) but the slider won't play.

I am using a simple if to check if stop is false.

This is my code:

```js
<script>

var stop = true;

$('.play').click(function(){
  stop = "false";
  alert(stop);

});


$(function(){
    alert(stop);
    if(stop == "false"){

    setInterval(swapSlides,3000);

    function swapSlides(){
 var cs = $('div.currentslide:first');
 var ns = cs.next();
 if(ns.hasClass('mySlides1')){
 cs.removeClass('currentslide');
 ns.addClass('currentslide');
    }
 else{
 ns = $('#polaroid1').children('div.mySlides1:first');
 cs.removeClass('currentslide');
 ns.addClass('currentslide');
 }
 }
 }
});
</script>
```

```css
.play{
 position:absolute; 
 left:5px; 
 bottom:5px; 
 cursor:pointer; 
 z-index:10000;
}

.polaroid1{
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
 transform: rotate(-8deg); 
 margin-bottom:30px; 
 width:380px; 
 height:320px; 
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0); 
 text-align:right; 
 padding-top:10px; 
 padding-right:10px; 
 padding-left:10px; 
 padding-bottom:15px; 
 top:15px; 
 left:25px; 
 position:relative;
}

.photo1{
 width:100%;  
 height:85%; 
 position:relative;
 padding:5px;
}

.date1{
 margin:0; 
 padding-right:10px; 
 font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; 
 transform: rotate(-5deg);
 font-size:28px;
}

.mySlides1{
 display:none;
 width:380px; 
 height:320px; 
 position:absolute; 
 top:0px; 
 left:0px;
}

.currentslide{display:block;}
```

```html
<div id="polaroid1" class="polaroid1">
  <img class="play" src="images/heart.png">
  <div class="mySlides1 fade currentslide">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0028.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170812_181516.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">12-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170522_112958.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0017.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">10-06-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170819_194526.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">19-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170811_182103.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">11-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170522_124602.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170419_020725.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">19-04-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170520_115819.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">20-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170822_011703.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170705_184344.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">05-07-2017</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You understand that the logic inside your document ready will only execute once on page load, right?   Given that your variable is initialized to true, the interval will never start with the logic you have.

Comment: I removed the fucntion from the document ready and now its a $(function(){ instead but  still doesn't work

Comment: $(function(){ ... }) is the same as a document ready.  But you didn't address the root problem.  Nothing about clicking the play button causes the other logic to happen.  An easy way to remedy this would be to move the logic related to starting the slideshow into a method, and inside that play click hander, **call** that method.

Comment: then how can I ivoke the function? I am js newbie

Comment: I edited the script in my OP with howit looks now

Answer (score 1):

You should place your play event listener inside the document ready function. You should avoid using global variables like so as it will lead to a polluted namespace.

Edit: as Taplar mentioned it isn't a scope issue. I didn't read your code thoroughly enough. Your code won't execute as you expect once you click.

Once the document is ready it will execute the alert(stop) and setInterval sequentially once and only once.

You have to execute your excepted actions within the event listener in order for them to work repeatedly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var stop = true;

    // Assume swapSlides is defined and can be called

    $('.play').click(function(){
        stop = false;
        alert(stop);
        setInterval(swapSlides, 3000);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it your boolean?

```
var stop = true;
```

I guess it is not boolean, but varchar :) 
If you want to use var as true or false:

```
$('.play').click(function(){
  stop = "false";
  alert(stop);
});
if(stop == "false"){
```

will work